# How do I connect an Ubuntu vm (esxi 6.5) to internet?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, esxi

Learning vmare/esxi/networking in home lab environment

1. I installed ESXi 6.5 on a macbook pro.
2. Then I connected it to a macbook air with an Ethernet adapter (usb-to-ethernet on macbook air)
3. Opened a web browser from my macbook air, entered host ip which gave me access to a beautiful software management tool (free web client) for my hypervisor.

However, I am unable to connect my newly installed Ubuntu vm to the internet. The hypervisor has internet.

(I believe the hypervisor is online because before I boot, I hold down option key which allows me to type the password for my wifi before booting. I’m assuming this is the correct way to get hypervisor online)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your setup.

So the MacBook Pro is running ESXi? 
And that MacBook is ONLY booting ESXi?
And the network of the MacBook Pro is connected to a switch or hub? 
The ESXi host is pingable from your MacAir? 
You DON'T have a direct cable between ESXi (MacBook Pro) and MacAir?

If all is yes, then:
On ESXi create a portgroup on the vSwitch that is already there. Probably you also see an existing portgroup named: "VM Network".
Connect your Ubuntu VM's network to that portgroup "VM Network".

My guess is that you don't have VLANs, so in the portgroup don't use VLAN IDs.

Configure networking inside your ubuntu VM with an ip address in the same range as your internet router's gateway.

This could work but you leave a lot of questions about your setup.

Comment: Yes to all your questions except that I actually DO have a physical ethernet cable connecting macbook pro and air. What would you suggest? I really appreciate your feedback Gabrie.

Comment: So the MacBook Pro has one network adapter and it is connected to the MacAir through a crosswired cable? Then the MacAir would have to perform routing from the crosswire cable to its wireless interface. Is there no way you can add a switch or hub in your config?

Comment: Hi Gabrie, I did what you said: "Configure networking inside your ubuntu VM with an ip address in the same range as your internet router's gateway." and I am having no luck. Been trying to find anyone with similar problem, but most search results are people using VMware Workstation--not esxi6.5.

Comment: Skype: gabrie.van.zanten. Add me and I'll chat with you about your setup and how to make this work